# How to load js files first before html in Internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a jquery treeview script for implementing a tree structure with li tags..when the page is loaded the ul tag is shown with out treeview structure for 1 ~ 2 sec then only it loads the js file.This is only happening in IE browser..rest all browsers are good..anyway to show treeview faster in ie
similarly 
In my html i have

```
<span id="hide"><img src="path/to/my/image" /></span>
```

And in my js i have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hide).hide():
});
```

But the image is shown for 1 sec then only it is hided..only happening in IE
Any help guys...sorry being too much elaborated :)

Comment: The above eg is a sample..My point is i need to load js before html in Internet explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to hide the image:

```
<span id="hide" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Ok thats the inline css..that will do fine ,but i need to  implement via external js the above code is just an example all i want is to load the js faster or before the html in Internet explorer

Comment: you have this problem because IE first downloads all the content (js, css, images, text) and then displays the page. FF/Chrome/Opera work in a different way (first text then display page then content), so you don't see the image from the very beginning (since it's considered "phase 2").
hiding it in first place is the best solution
EDIT: didn't want this to be a comment, but i used the wrong box, sorry :(

Comment: Any hack for this Samuele Mattiuzzo ? :)

Answer (score 1):

set css `"display:none"` of your container element.

then at

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".containerElement").fadeIn("fast", function(){
        $(".containerElement").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

this will fix the styleless tree.

Comment: Thanks @Billa That code is just an example..My requirement is that i want to load js files before html in Internet explorer

Comment: you cannot interrupt the loading behavior of page, if js is in head it will be called first, what you can do is hide the element until the js is loaded, then show it.

Comment: just like Samuele Mattiuzzo said, hiding it is best solution.

Comment: Thanks guys..hiding the element till it is loaded is the only solution in IE i think..:)

Comment: IE is just like a disabled person, you have to treat them carefully :)